# Lectura Input sin presionar enter y sin esperar [consola C++]

Tags: c++, windows, consola

estoy intentando hacer una suerte de juego con la consola, en lenguaje C++.

El juego es un tipo clicker, pero con teclas. La idea por ahora, es que cuando pulse "enter" produzca una unidad de algo (todas las veces que de tiempo antes de que se repita el bucle) y al final de cada bucle mis clientes me quitan una unidad de ese algo.

Por esto necesito leer la entrada del teclado para ver si en el bucle se ha pulsado enter para producir unidades. Si el usuario no pulsa "enter" antes de que termine el bucle, pues en ese bucle no se produce ninguna unidad de nada. Por lo tanto necesito un metodo de lectura que detecte "en tiempo real" si se pulsa determinada tecla o no, por eso estoy usando la funcion getch() de la libreria conio.h

La cosa es que no consigo saber cual es el valor de retorno de getch(), el cual pueda usar para la condicion if tal y como se ve en el ejemplo:

```
//LOOP PROGRAMA
   while (actividad == true){
      
   system("clear");
  
    cout<<"Bienvenido a tu empresa \n";
   cout<<"Zumos totales creados: "<<zumosTotalesCreados;
   cout<<"\nZumos en Stock: "<<stockZumos;
   cout<<"\nPulsa Enter para crear un zumo"<<endl;
   
  decision =getch(); //Leer INPUT Jugador
  
  //Logica INPUT jugador
   if(decision == 'enter') {
       stockZumos = stockZumos +1 ;
       zumosTotalesCreados = zumosTotalesCreados + 1;
   }
  //FIN logica INPUT jugador
    
  //Logica IA 
  
  stockZumos--;
 //FIN logica IA
 
 
  sleep(1);
 
 
   }//FIN DE LOP PROGRAMA
```

Si igualmente a alguien se le ocurre otra manera de hacerlo, soy todo oidos.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0):

Dices que quieres leer caracter a caracter, luego `decision` debería ser una variable de tipo `char`. Un `char`, por definición, solo puede almacenar **un caracter**, luego de ninguna forma puedes almacenar una secuencia de caracteres tipo 'enter'.

Los caracteres que vas a leer son los que están representados en cualquier tabla ASCII. Ahí puedes ver que al salto de línea le corresponde el caracter número 0x0A. En C++ también puede representarse como `\n`

**EDICIÓN**

Hay un problema, y es que `getch` **no devuelve saltos de línea**. Si deberías poder detectar, en cambio, el caracter de retorno de carro `\r`:

```
char decision = getch();
if (decision == '\r')
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Buenas, en primer lugar, gracias por tu respuesta. La gracia de usar "getch()" es que ese metodo permite detectar pulsaciones sin necesidad del salto de linea.  std::cin.get(); no avanza la ejecución del programa hasta que se pulsa la tecla. mientras que getch() sí que lo permite.

Comment: @AlexMartínez cierto, bien visto. Es una función que yo no tiendo a utilizar por su nula portabilidad. El resto de la respuesta, en cualquier caso, sigue siendo válida aun usando `getch()`

Comment: el problema en todo esto es que al hacer la comprobacion, que ahora he cambiado por if (decision == '\n')
{
    // ...
}    la comprobación no funciona porque el valor que me devuelve getch() o no me lo devuelve bien o no corresponde o yo que se. Ahi es donde viene el problema que me da ganas de llorar.  No se si podría ser cosa de estar usando un compilador online.